# I've lost my display (after trying to send it to another screen)

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, screen-sharing, blank-screen

I have lost the display on my primary screen. I wanted to test sharing my desktop with my TV screen, and I have done it before, but this time I forgot to connect my TV to the home network, and when I selected the option on the PC, my screen went blank.

I was then without a display. I tried rebooting the computer but that didn't work.

How can I get the display back on my primary screen? I know I can do it with shortcuts (charms bar > devices > project > top option) but I don't remember the shortcuts and I couldn't find [all of] them online on my phone.

Comment: `Hi my computer screen is dead I mean it's lost... in cyberspace somewhere or something.` - I have no idea what it is you're trying to explain. Your post is unclear as it currently stands, edit and it convert it to something we can understand or we can't help :(.

Comment: Try holding the windows key and pressing `P` twice. Then wait about 20 seconds. Then try again.  This should be roughly equivalent to bringing up the projection options and then selecting the next option.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

Unplug the HDMI cable and plug it into a different HDMI port. If you have a second port.

I still can't get the scene to show if I put it back into the original,port though.

Comment: When/If you figure out how to fix this be sure to come back here and tell us how by editing this answer.

Comment: Of course!. :-)

Comment: I have solved this issue. I will update shortly.